# Tablespaces used to create a materialized view?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views, tablespace

I'm trying to create a view as such:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED ReasonableSizedView
TABLESPACE MyMediumTS
AS 
select COUNT(something) AS allsomethings,
    thetype AS thing,
    status
from SomeMassiveTable
where
    thetype = 'x'
    AND status IN (0,1,2,3)
GROUP BY
    thetype,
    status;
```

And all I get is an error: `ORA-01658`: unable to create INITIAL extent for segment in tablespace **MySmallTS**

Okay, now, `MySmallTS` is the *default* ts for the user I'm trying to create the view - and it is full. The thing of a full table space, is a problem apart, and is being dealt with, but why on earth is Oracle trying to use it for this view even though I'm explicitly telling where I want it?

Further more, if I change the query a and remove the `group by`'s, it will work, *and it will create the view in the correct table space*.

I wonder, the whole operation of grouping and summing and stuff, shouldn't that be using the `TEMP` table space assigned for that user? That would seem reasonable, and by the way, my temp has plenty of space...

why is that so?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that it works when removing the GROUP BY, my guess is that MySmallTS is also assigned as the default *temporary* tablespace for that user.

Building the intermediate result will be done in the temporary tablespace and when using the GROUP BY this gets too big for MySmallTS

Comment: No, not really.. I double checked that. My user really has a proper table space set as temp (I mean, different than ``MySmallTS``). :(